# Generic Type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

Please explain why this doesn't work? What is it about the constraint `IPoolable<T>` that the compiler doesn't like? Is it because the generic `IPoolable<T>` is really just a "template" and there is no inheritance between `PoolItem` and `IPollable<T>`?

In the code

```
public class GenericPool<TPoolable> where TPoolable : IPoolable<T>
```

while can't `T` be interpreted as long?

Full code listing:

```
    public interface IPoolable<T> where T : new()
    {
        T PooledObject { get; }
    }

    public class PoolItem : IPoolable<long>
    {
        private readonly long _id;

        public long PooledObject
        {
            get { return _id; }
        }
    }

    public class GenericPool<TPoolable> where TPoolable : IPoolable<T>
    {
        public T Borrow()
        {
            var item = default(TPoolable);
            return item.PooledObject;
        }

        public void Return(T item)
        {

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pool = new GenericPool<PoolItem>();
        }
    }
```

Just to be clear, I know that I can change GenericPool to

```
public class GenericPool<TPoolable, T> where TPoolable : IPoolable<T> where T : new()
```

I am not asking how to fix this code. Instead I am asking the question; why do I have to add T as a type parameter to GenericPool in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `IPoolable<T>` as a constraint because the generic type parameter `T` isn't known in that context. As you surmise, `IPoolable<T>` is essentially a blueprint for an infinite number of types, so without binding `T` to *something* (for example, a type parameter of the `GenericPool` class) it doesn't make sense as a constraint.

The actual error message you should be getting is `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found`, which makes sense: `T` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: I understand that T "isn't defined" in the GenericPool class but IPoolable<T> is defined. Why do I have to define T twice?

Comment: The `T` in `IPoolable<T>` is only relevant in the declaration of the interface itself. Outside of that, `IPoolable<>` has to be declared with a combination of actual types and valid type parameters between the `<` and the `>` (with the notable exception of `typeof(IPoolable<>)` ). Since `T` is neither a valid type, nor a currently useable type parameter, you don't have valid code.

Comment: no, `IPoolable<T>` isn't defined either, because compiler doesn't know what `T` is. The only thing that is defined is generic `IPoolable` interface, which should be parametrized with a type before instantiation.